# Set the size of a float array from a method outside the class (Or a GLKVector structure)

Tags: objective-c, c

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to accomplish the following:

I am using xcode storyboards, to pass a value or alter a value i am supposed to use a segue which basically lets me call a method of a new class (view) in the previews one, to set a value on the target view.

so i have this on my previews view:

```
ARViewController *temp = segue.destinationViewController;
[temp setDrawableArray:temp];
```

Here temp is a structure i defined, this structure has an int which i want to use to set the size of an array in the new class.

the new class goes at follows on the variable declaration in the Header File:

```
@interface ARViewController : UIViewController <GLKViewDelegate>
{
    GLKVector3 drawableArray;
}
- (void)setDrawableArray:(Kanji)temp;

@end
```

Here i would like to ask if that declaration is ok, or if it should be something like

```
GLKVector3 *drawableArray;
```

(GLKVector is just a structure of floats, so it could easely be replaced by float drawableArray)

On the Implementation of the class (.m) I have the method:

```
- (void)setDrawableArray:(Kanji)temp
{
    drawableArray = GLKVector3 drawableArray[5];
    //Here i want to do some operations to the newly created array

}
```

This is of course wrong, I have no idea about how to set the array size, if anyone would be so kind to tell me i would appreciate it a lot.

PD: The array has to be global for the class because I will use it in different places within that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-object array handling is the same in Obj-C as in C. To declare a dynamic global array you need to declare a variable of type *pointer* to an array, just as you declare pointers to Obj-C objects. However in C there is really no difference between a pointer to a single value and a pointer to an array of values, so your second declaration is correct:

```
GLKVector3 *drawableArray;
```

To allocate the array use `calloc(number of elements, size of each element)`, e.g. to create a 5 element array:

```
drawableArray = calloc(5, sizeof(GLKVector3));
```

When you've finished with the array you must release it with `free()`:

```
free(drawableArray);
```

And finally remember there is **no** array bounds checking, so when indexing you must do you own checks or you will read/write random memory.

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast reply, whats the difference between this and drawableArray = reallocf(drawableArray, sizeof(GLKVector3)*temp.totalpoints); Also, I am using XCODE, which uses ARC (automatic reference counting) i just dont know if this works only for objects or also for primitives, you dont suppose there will be a problem if i simply write the free(drawableArray) on the view did unload, do you?

Comment: (1) `realloc` is for changing the size of an already allocated block - you get either (a) the same block back with its size changed or (b) a new block back with the contents of the original block copied over and the original is freed. `reallocf` is a variant which frees the original block even if there is not enough space to create a new one. Try typing `man 3 reallocf` in the Terminal for more details. (2) ARC (and GC or manual alloc/retain/release) and the C `malloc` family are independent and used for different purposes. You can put the `free` anywhere you no longer require the memory.